How to expand prop_gput key/value?
In the LaTeX 3 documentation I can't find prop_gput:Nxx. How can I expand the key and/or value in a property list?

https://texdoc.org/serve/interface3/0#page=225

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_example_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddProp}{+m+m}{
    \prop_gput:Noo \g_example_prop {#1} {#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintProp}{}{
    \prop_if_empty:NF \g_example_prop {
        \begin{itemize}
            \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_example_prop {
                \item ##1:~##2
            }
        \end{itemize}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AddProp{\texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];}}{true}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];} true
\end{itemize}
\PrintProp
\end{document}

Actual output: 
Expected output: 

Please extend your example to a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Note that in general you rarely need x expansion, e ought to be enough.

You're not using a property list correctly here. You are storing a value in the key. And the  key are treated differently. I would have assumed your usage to be \AddProp{foobar}{\texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];}, then it should work just fine.

Think of the property list as a dictionary in Python or a hash in Perl. The key is mostly expected to be a string, whereas the value can be more or less anything.

(and you do not need expl3 on a modern installation)

Property names are saved as strings and they shouldn't contain typesetting instructions. You might rescan them, but it's not the recommended method, in my opinion.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_user_example_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddProp}{m+m}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_user_example_prop {#1} {#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintProp}{}
 {
  \prop_if_empty:NF \g_user_example_prop
   {
    \begin{itemize}
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_user_example_prop { \item \tl_rescan:nn {}{##1}:~##2 }
    \end{itemize}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddProp{\texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];}}{true}

\PrintProp

\end{document}

I'd do it with to paired sequences.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_user_example_a_seq
\seq_new:N \g_user_example_b_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddProp}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_user_example_a_seq {#1}
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_user_example_b_seq {#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintProp}{}
 {
  \seq_if_empty:NF \g_user_example_a_seq
   {
    \begin{itemize}
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN
     \g_user_example_a_seq % first sequence
     \g_user_example_b_seq % second sequence
     \__user_example_item:nn % action
    \end{itemize}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_example_item:nn { \item #1:~#2 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddProp{\texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];}}{true}

\PrintProp

\end{document}



I'd do it with TeX primitives.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\AddProp#1#2{\ifx\propdata\undefined \def\propdata{\item #1: #2}%
                 \else \addto\propdata{\item #1: #2}%
                 \fi
}
\def\PrintProp {%
   \ifx\propdata\undefined \else
        \begin{itemize} \propdata \end{itemize}
   \fi
}

\AddProp{\texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];}}{true}
\AddProp{\texttt{Double[] x = new Integer[6];}}{false}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];} true
\end{itemize}
\PrintProp
\end{document}


I guess OP needs multiple calls to \AddProp and then retrieve the data added with each during \PrintProp, so something like \AddProp{foo}{bar}\AddProp{Foo}{Bar}\PrintProp should print both foo and Foo.

If you for some reason want to continue using a prop (for instance because you need fast access to single elements of your data and not only want to map against the entire thing), you could also place the key in an unaltered manner into the value of your prop and then use \use_i:nn or \use_ii:nn to access the data:
\documentclass{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_example_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddProp}{+m+m}
  {
    \prop_gput:Noo \g_example_prop {#1} { {#1} {#2} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintProp}{}
  {
    \prop_if_empty:NF \g_example_prop
      {
        \begin{itemize}
          \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_example_prop
            { \item \use_i:nn ##2:~ \use_ii:nn ##2 }
        \end{itemize}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\AddProp{\texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];}}{true}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{Double[] d = new Integer[6];} true
\end{itemize}
\PrintProp
\end{document}

